# On passing exceptions from C++ to C#

Tags: mono, interop

In a [webpage](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) it's suggested that:

> The moral of this story: don’t let exceptions propagate between managed and unmanaged code. The results won’t be pretty.

also suggested:

> This is particularly pertinent when wrapping C++ methods. C++ exceptions will need to be mapped into an “out” parameter or a return value, so that managed code can know what error occurred, and (optionally) throw a managed exception to “propagate” the original C++ exception.

Based on the above statements, my understanding is that the safest (best?) way to pass exceptions from C++ to C# is by **return value** or **output parameter**. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Few exception handling frameworks (irrespective of managed or native) are even remotely compatible. Thus, on any module-boundary, yes, you have to marshal any possible exception, which most likely looses at least some information. C++ to C# interoperation (pinvoke or embedding) isn't except.

Comment: Unmanaged code *does* participate in stack unwinding on Windows, this problem is specific to *nix variants.  Mentioning your specific target OS would be wise.